# Select data from a table name based on a GET parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET MVC 4

Entity Framework : 6.1.3

I'm trying to select data from a table name based on a GET parameter **"form"**.

**My controller contains the following code:**

```
...

using System.Linq;

...

public ActionResult Index(string form, int? page)
{
    Type MyTable1Type, MyTable2Type;

    Dictionary<string, Type> TableType = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        { "MyTable1", MyTable1Type},
        { "MyTable2", MyTable2Type}
    };

    var query = db.Set(TableType[form]);

    var records = query.Select(x => x).Where(x => (!x.user_action.user.email.ToLower().Contains("@example.com")));

    // Pagination

    int PageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
    var results = records.OrderByDescending(x => x.user_action.date_created).ToList().ToPagedList(PageIndex, PageSize);

    return View(results);
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can you guys help? Thanks. :)

Comment: what is `typeof (query )`? `DbSet` doesn't support `Select`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Considering that your `Select` does absolutely nothing of value, the easiest fix is to just not use it.

Comment: @Chris and then the next question is "But Where() doesn't work". It's because `Set()` isn't generic. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626844/generic-method-to-retrieve-dbsett-from-dbcontext.

Comment: What's your end game here? Do all of these potential "forms" inherit from the same base type or implement the same interface?